# android recording app not working across smart phone

Tags: android

We have developed a android application which is use for the call recording of our office executive and shift these recording to our local server. Every recorded calls are saved on the server smoothly. This Application working on MicroMax Bharat 1 but we have noticed that this application is unable to perform on all latest smart phones. Application (background services/process) automatically stop after 30-40 min. Can any one suggest us the solution.

Comment: From what you have just described that is a problem with the Android OS itself which will shutdown apps in background if they are not used regularly. It also dependes on the OEMs specific implementation/flavour or Android, but normally you can whitelist the app in the Settings -> Apps -> your app and then under Batter or something like that there might be an option unrestrict background processing.